# Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId is appearing twice in http response header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am facing an issue where Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId is appearing twice in HTTP header response.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code, or more information ?

Comment: Do you encounter any issue besides appearing twice?

Comment: No others issue was observed. To give you a context, Its a sitecore MVC solution.